# How do I access the value of variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my `.h` file

```
@interface DemoApp : UIViewController   {
    UITextView *textView;
@private

    NSString *status;

    NSInteger *track1Len,*track2Len;


}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *status;
```

In `.m` file

```
    @synthesize status;
- (void)onDecodeCompleted:(NSString *)sts
{
   status=sts;
   NSLog(@"status is %@",status);

}

- (IBAction)processButton:(id)sender
{
   NSLog(@"status is %@",status);
   // here I am getting null value
}
```

I just to access my variable throughout my class file.In ondecodecompleted method,I am getting the value that is passed as parameter but after the process button is pressed I am getting null value.

Comment: `self.status = sts;` and read up on properties...

Comment: It has not been necessary to declare backing iVars for years now, and synthesizing variables was made optional a few months ago.

Comment: Can you nslog sts in that first function, that might be null to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try: `self.status` in both places.

```
- (void)onDecodeCompleted:(NSString *)sts
{
   self.status=sts;
   NSLog(@"status is %@",self.status);

}

- (IBAction)processButton:(id)sender
{
   NSLog(@"status is %@",self.status);
   // here I am getting null value
}
```

Also since you are using `NSString` which has a mutable subclass, you should mark it as `copy` and not `retain`

`@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *status;`

Answer (score 0):

The Reason why you are losing your iVar is because you are not getting `ownership` on your variable when you are setting it directly.
You need to do `status = [sts copy];` OR `status = [sts retain]` to take ownership.
If you don't take ownership `status` will have the life span of `sts`which is probably not what you want.

Accessing iVar directly is usually a bad idea because of the local memory management that you need to remember to do right each time.
The best practice is to use your `@property` with `dot syntax`. the property will take care of the memory management of setters accordingly to the one you will have declared.